# How to block InterstitialAd (GMS )in android apps (sdk 8)

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

Im not programmer and need your help. Im using Admob (InterstitialAd) in my app. SDK 8 does not support my GMS library. How to block Ad in apps with sdk 8. I found the code but dont know how to use it properly.
**if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)**

```
package com.training;




public class NoAuthorisationMainActivity extends Activity {

......................

private InterstitialAd interstitial;

...............

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


      Resources resource = getResources();
        Configuration config = resource.getConfiguration();
        sharedPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
         if ("ru".equalsIgnoreCase(sharedPreference.getString("language", null))) {
                config.locale = RUSSIAN;
            } else if ("en".equalsIgnoreCase(sharedPreference.getString("language", null))) {
                config.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;

            } else if ("es".equalsIgnoreCase(sharedPreference.getString("language", null))) {   
                config.locale = SPANISH;
            }
            else {
                config.locale = Locale.getDefault();
            }
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);

    Log.v( "DEBUG", "Main activity starting" );
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity); // ID Activity


    Button languageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GoLanguageButton);
    languageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
   //               Intent LanguageButton = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LanguageLocale.class);
   //               MainActivity.this.startActivity(LanguageButton);
            langDialog().show();
        }
    });





      new DBData(this);

        // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(NoAuthorisationMainActivity.this);
        // Insert the Ad Unit ID
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(MY_AD_UNIT_ID);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("6c248b7677c6609d")
        .build();

        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Call displayInterstitial() function
                displayInterstitial();
            }
        });




    findViewById(R.id.noAuthInfo).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent BookButton = new Intent(NoAuthorisationMainActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
            NoAuthorisationMainActivity.this.startActivity(BookButton);
        }
    });


    findViewById(R.id.noAuthTreker).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent TrackerButton = new Intent(NoAuthorisationMainActivity.this, ShowExercisesListActivity.class);
                NoAuthorisationMainActivity.this.startActivity(TrackerButton);
        }
    });


    findViewById(R.id.noAuthInfo2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(NoAuthorisationMainActivity.this, DnevnikTrenirovokActivity.class);
            NoAuthorisationMainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    findViewById(R.id.noAuthTimer).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent TimerButton = new Intent(NoAuthorisationMainActivity.this, TimerMain.class);
            NoAuthorisationMainActivity.this.startActivity(TimerButton);
        }
    });


    findViewById(R.id.noAuthBtnAuth).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            startActivity(new Intent(NoAuthorisationMainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
    });


    findViewById(R.id.noAuthBtnRegistration).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            startActivity(new Intent(NoAuthorisationMainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
        }
    });








}



private void showMessage(String message)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);

//        checkMessage(intent);

    setIntent(new Intent());
}

 // Create Menu
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) // Build menu
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_menu, menu); // ID mainmenu for the menu
        return true;
    }


 // The menus with icons
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) // Set cases if you click on the menu button
        {

        case R.id.close: // Close WebView
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent); 
            return true;
        case R.id.google: // Open new WebView with the e.g. Google Url
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                    Uri.parse("http://gym-training.com/")));

            return true;





        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            // You can build more menus and more cases if you like.

        }

    }

    private Dialog langDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.personal_setting);
        String[] mas = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.language_sort_options);

        final Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

        builder.setItems(mas, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch(which) {
                case 0:
                    sharedPreference.edit().putString("language", "auto").commit();
                    config.locale = Locale.getDefault();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    sharedPreference.edit().putString("language", "en").commit();
                    config.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    sharedPreference.edit().putString("language", "ru").commit();
                    config.locale = RUSSIAN;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    sharedPreference.edit().putString("language", "es").commit();
                    config.locale = SPANISH;
                    break;
                }

                getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);

                Intent intent = new Intent(NoAuthorisationMainActivity.this, NoAuthorisationMainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);
    }

    public void displayInterstitial() {
        // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is hard to anticipate the state of each device, you must always check for a compatible Google Play services APK before you access Google Play services features rather than sdk version

To verify the Google Play services version, call "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()". If the result code is SUCCESS, then the Google Play services APK is up-to-date and you can continue to make a connection. If, however, the result code is SERVICE_MISSING, SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, or SERVICE_DISABLED, then the user needs to install an update. So, call GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog() and pass it the result error code. This returns a Dialog you should show, which provides an appropriate message about the error and provides an action that takes the user to Google Play Store to install the update.